# SQL query for listing items that don't have a current date-stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help writing a query to display a list of measurement devices that have not reported a recording to us AND the number of days since last recording.

Here's the table structure:

```
select d.deviceno, r.lastrecordingdate, --Here's where i need a table to act as a COUNT for --number of days the device has not logged.
from modules m
join devices d on m.deviceid = d.deviceid
join recordings r on m.recordingid = r.recordingid
--i really don't know what to write beyond this. I am drawin
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS-SQL, Access, something else ?

Comment: `Here's the table structure:` This is not a table structure, but a query from which it might or might not be possible to infer the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.deviceno, 
       DateDiff(day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, max_date) AS days_since
  FROM (
          SELECT D.deviceno,
                 COALESCE(MAX(R.last_recordingdate), '2000-01-01') AS max_date
            FROM Modules M
                 INNER JOIN Devices D
                    ON M.deviceid = D.deviceid
                 LEFT JOIN Recordings R 
                    ON M.recordingid = R.recordingid
                 GROUP BY D.deviceno
        ) FOO
  WHERE max_date < DateAdd(day, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Since you didn't specify the database, I'm using SQL Server specific syntax (the date math functions).    The COALESCE is to make sure that we capture devices that haven't recorded anything at all.

Comment: I am getting this error in the console when running Curt's script.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'.

Comment: Okay thanks! That fixed THAT error, now I have a another error:

Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: @user2482608    Okay, I re-crafted the query to use a different approach.   I'm not sure of the schema here, so I can't test first, but this should work...